# Not able to print AfxMessagBox() After doModal() method

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

```
BOOL CmsgboxApp::InitInstance()  
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;  
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);  
    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;  
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);  
    CWinApp::InitInstance();  
    AfxEnableControlContainer();  
    SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));  
    CmsgboxDlg dlg;  
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;  
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();  
    if (nResponse == IDOK)  
    {  
        AfxMessageBox(L"here",0,0);//This MessageBox is not getting displayed  
    }  
    else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)  
    {  
    }  
    return FALSE;  
}
```

In above code `AfxMessageBox()` is not getting displayed.
Why this problem is coming?

First I created Modal DialogBox and After return from it I tried to provide Message box
But it is not displayed

Comment: Have you stepped through it in a debugger? What does the `DoModal` call return?

Comment: it returned IDOk. ALso I tried to use AfxMessagBox() before return;But stil it is not dislplayed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it may be that `AfxMessageBox` does not provide its own message pump like `CDialog::DoModal()` does. I would assume `AfxMessageBox` just calls the Win32 `MessageBox()` function, which would require a message pump to dispatch the painting / click messages etc.

**EDIT:**
Windows programs work by passing messages around. All Windows programs have a message "pump" that process any incoming messages to do things like painting the screen, and reacting to mouse clicks etc. Originally you had to code the message pump yourself.

MFC came along and provided a message pump for you. There is one in `CWinApp::Run()` for normal SDI/MDI applications, and one in `CDialog::DoModal()` for dialog based applications (and modal dialogs in general).

The code you have posted is a dialog based MFC application. The "application" is the dialog. Once you have returned from that dialog, there is no message pump and the application is pretty much dead. You should be doing very little after this, possibly some cleanup. Certainly not displaying more information.

If you want to display more information on close, then override `OnClose()` in your application dialog, and call `AfxMessageBox()` there.

Comment: So how could use Message box to give some usefull message to user on IDOK?

Comment: @Ganeshkumar A modal dialog contains its own message loop. For other things you might have to implement your own message loop. Do a Google search for "message loop" or "message pump".

Comment: This option of writing code in OnClose() is very much useful for me to do important work over ther. Thanks a lot @GazTheDestroyer for your knowledge sharing

Answer (score 0):

You should put the message in the dialog's OnOK() handler, it is exactly the same as when the dialog returns IDOK.

The AfxMessageBox() doesn't get displayed because it has no owner window at this point. If you debug into AfxMessageBox() you will eventually fall into CWinApp::ShowAppMessageBox(...) function where the following gets called:

```
HWND hWnd = CWnd::GetSafeOwner_(NULL, &hWndTop);
```

Since owner window is NULL now as dialog has existed, message box will not get displayed.

Comment: But in my case I need to do some work after DoModal() call.So I am concerned about why it is not printing messagebox after DoModal().

Comment: I edited my post to add more information. What is stopping you from doing work in OnOK()? It's the right place because in error condition you may not want to exist the GUI which you can easily control from there.

Comment: Thanks @zadane for your quick reply. I tried to debug and found same reason of NULL handle for parent window. Iwill try to sheep my code in side OnOK()